# How to Redirect to Area Controller to Root Controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created Area named as "**FlipBook**" and inside it, I have created controller "**Invitation**". I've view inside "**index**" action of invitation controller. In this view I have action link which redirects to me root controller action.

[image]
In view I've created Action link using following code.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area="" })">Click to Confirm</a>
```

But it redirects me to same area "**FlipBook**". but my expected action is not under same area and its in root controller.

Comment: `<a href='/Home/Index'>Click to Confirm</a>`

Comment: @Eric : can't I use Url.Action? I can use alternate but eager to know answer for Url.Action

Comment: I had the same problem, but can't find a solution with Url.Action, so I decided to use the plain HTML.

Comment: ok. lets see can someone help us both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me below line is working fine with new { area="" } to redirect root controller.

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area="" })">Click to Confirm</a>
```

Check you default route configured in `RegisterRoutes` in  `RouteConfig.cs` .Configure default route to route action which is not in area "FlipBook". that would fix your issue.
for.e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: I have the same problem, how can we fix that in netcore 5 ?